# Nanosecond precision in DataFrame output

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

`DataFrame`'s HTML output looks to be formatting `timedelta64` objects to microsecond precision, i.e. 6 decimal places.

[image: DataFrame showing times to microsecond precision]

How can I increase this to nanosecond precision, 9 decimal places?

**Edit:** source code from the above image:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy import timedelta64

DataFrame([
    dict(delta=timedelta64(1234, 'ns')),
    dict(delta=timedelta64(56789, 'ns'))
])

<Jupyter html table showing two times, each with the nanoseconds portion truncated>
```

Comment: this is just a representation - if you would save it to file - it will be stored correctly: `df.to_csv(r'/path/to/out.csv', index=False)`

Comment: the intent is probably to be able to display it in a notebook without having to write to file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `DataFrame.style.format` and manually convert the `timedelta64` object to nanoseconds:

```
(
    DataFrame([
        dict(delta=np.timedelta64(1234, 'ns')),
        dict(delta=np.timedelta64(56789, 'ns'))
    ])
    .style.format(dict(delta=lambda td: td / np.timedelta64(1, 'ns')))
)

    delta
0  1234.0
1 56789.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a display issue. The full precision is stored in the dataframe. You can display the exact values by viewing the np array representation of the row:

```
df.delta.values
```